# all possible combinations of movements of branch pointer, HEAD, index and working tree

Tags: git

What operations could be carried out to get all possible combinations of movement of:

- branch pointer
- HEAD
- index
- working tree

Assume that we have this layout:

```
* 1234567 (HEAD -> K, b) 2nd
* 7654321 (a) 1st
```

We are currently on branch K. Branches `a` and `b` are setup for convenience to write the examples

Answer (score 0):

## Single movement

### branch pointer

```
git checkout --detach; git branch -f K a
```

### HEAD

```
git checkout --detach a; git restore --worktree --staged --source=b .
```

Or, the way of the old days (still works):

```
git checkout --detach a; git checkout b -- .
```

### index

```
git restore --staged --source=a .
```

### working tree

```
git restore --worktree --source=a .
```

## combinations of 2 items

### branch pointer and HEAD

```
git reset --soft a
```

### branch pointer and index or working tree:

Run the 2 items to move them separately.

### HEAD and index

```
git checkout --detach a; git restore --worktree --source=b .
```

### HEAD and working tree

```
git checkout --detach a; git restore --staged --source=b .
```

### index and working tree

```
git restore --worktree --staged --source=a .
```

In the old days:

```
git checkout a -- .
```

## combinations of 3 items

### all *except* branch pointer

```
git checkout --detach b
```

### all except HEAD

```
git checkout --detach; git branch -f K a; git restore --staged --worktree --source=a .
```

### all except index

```
git reset --hard a; git restore --staged --source=b .
```

### all except working tree

```
git reset a
```

## Move everything

```
git reset --hard a
```